# Is there a program to run different commands simoultaneously in BASH terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I tried using GNU Parallel, but I couldn't find a way to run simoultaneously commands such as top and ls.

Comment: Use `tmux` or `screen` to share the scren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wait` to do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ls &
declare ls_pid=$!
top &
declare top_pid=$! 
wait "$ls_pid" "$top_pid"
```

[`$!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_0021) capture the background job pid and [wait](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait) simply wait for
them to exit.

Or you could use `tmux` and have two *windows*, one with ls, one with top.